# Linear Algebra Done Right – Exercise 5.A.25

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Suppose $T \in L(V)$ and $u$, $v$ are eigenvectors of $T$ such that $u+v$ is also an eigenvector for $T$. Prove that $u$ and $v$ are eigenvectors of $T$ corresponding to the same eigenvalue.

---

How should I go about proving this? I know that distinct eigenvalues have distinct eigenvectors that are linearly independent. $u+v$ is not independent of $u$ or $v$, so at most there are 2 distinct eigenvalues between $u$, $v$, and $u+v$. I'm not sure how to get further than this though.

Comment: What does $L(V)$ mean?

Comment: I guess linear map acting on V

Comment: Use the fact that T is linear and the definition of eigenvectors to show that u and v are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\;\alpha,\beta\;$ are the eigenvalues corresponding to $\;u,v\;$ resp., and let $\;\gamma\;$ be the eigenvalue for $\;u+v\;$, then

$$\gamma(u+v)=T(u+v)=Tu+Tv=\alpha u+\beta v\implies(\alpha-\gamma)u+(\beta-\gamma)v=0$$

But $\;u,v\;$ are linear independent since $\;\alpha\neq \beta\;$ , so...

Answer (score 0):

Let $T(u) = \lambda_1 u$, $T(v) = \lambda_2 v$, and $T(u+v) = \lambda_3 (u+v)$.

Adding the first two equations, and equating that to the third one, we obtain: \begin{equation}(\lambda_1 - \lambda_3) u = (\lambda_3 - \lambda_2) v .\label{a}\end{equation}

Pre-multiply both sides of the last equations by $T$ to obtain $$(\lambda_1 - \lambda_3) Tu = (\lambda_3 - \lambda_2) Tv \implies \lambda_1(\lambda_1 - \lambda_3) u = \lambda_2(\lambda_3 - \lambda_2) v$$ which implies $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$.